# Display checkbox value in textbox in the order of click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am new to Javascript my query is

How to Display the value of Check Box in the order of user clicked

Suppose i have

```
Apple
Orange
Pineapple
Mango
```

when user click the following order i.e

```
Pineapple
Apple
Mango
Orange
```

I need to display in same order in text box 
i was following link
 but it does not follow order I clicked please do help me.

SCRIPT

```
$('.check').click(function () {
    alert("subhash");
    $("#text").val('');
    $(".check").each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $("#text").val($("#text").val() + $(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
 <div id="checkboxes"> <b>Apple
<input type="checkbox" name="Apple" class="check" value="1"></b> <b>Orange
<input type="checkbox" name="Orange" class="check" value="2"></b> <b>Banana
<input type="checkbox" name="Banana" class="check" value="3"></b> 
</div> <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
```

Comment: Show your html too. Do we want to assume that too!!!

Comment: $('.check').click(function(){
  alert("subhash");
      $("#text").val('');
      $(".check").each(function(){
          if($(this).prop('checked')){
              
              $("#text").val($("#text").val()+$(this).val());
          }
      });
  });
 <div id="checkboxes">
  <b>Apple<input type="checkbox" name="Apple" class="check" value="1"></b>
  <b>Orange<input type="checkbox" name="Orange" class="check" value="2"></b>
  <b>Banana<input type="checkbox" name="Banana" class="check" value="3"></b>
 </div>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text">

Comment: @user3131594 don't put your code here...put it in your post and format it with ctrl+k or with 4 spaces. Two backticks (`) wrapping the code will also work for short segments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could do it. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/iDUsesiG/1/edit)**

**Markup:**

```
  <div id="inputs">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Apple">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Orange">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Pineapple">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Mango">
  </div>
  <ul id="results"></ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#inputs input').change(function() {
  $li = $('<li></li>');
  $li.text(this.value);
  $('#results').append($li);
});
```

If you want to remove items when they're unchecked and prevent duplicates, you could do this: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/iDUsesiG/2/edit)**

```
$('#inputs input').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $li = $('<li></li>');
    $li.text(this.value);
    $('#results').append($li);
  }
  else {
    $('li:contains('+this.value+')', '#results').remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you valuable reply !! in your solution 1. when user clcik on checkbox each time it displaying (So my requirement is i should display only at once 2. when user deselect the value should not be shown !! please do help me on that .

Comment: @user3131594 are you saying that's a bad thing? It isn't clear what you want. Anyway, I updated my answer with something you that might be helpful. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. If answers are helpful you can give them an upvote and also click accept (the arrow) on the best one.

Comment: it is clear. If checkbox is unchecked then it should be removed from the list. If he check it again then it should come last.

Comment: @SubinJacob my answer does that.

Comment: yes it does now. I think earlier it wasn't or I checked the other answer link instead.