# jQuery checked checkbox value shown in input textbox and uncheck will remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, checkbox

I've been trying to find the solution as said in my title where when you have multiple checkboxes and when you check a checkbox with the value such as "blood" will be added to an input textbox. Each checked value in the textbox will be separated either with space or a comma. When you uncheck a checkbox the value corresponding to it will be removed from the textbox.

So far the closest example i've came across is from this one: [Display checkbox value in textbox in the order of click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755892/display-checkbox-value-in-textbox-in-the-order-of-click)

I've tried to change the code around a bit by using `<input type="text" name="text" id="results" value="" />` and having `$li.text(this.value);` to `$li.val(this.value);` but nothing appears. Unfortunately jQuery isn't what I specialize in.

If possible can someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://jsbin.com/iDUsesiG/41/edit?html,js,output) is what you need?

```
var arr = [];
$('#inputs input').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    arr.push(this.value);
  }
  else {
   arr.splice(arr.indexOf(this.value), 1);
  }
  $('#target').val(arr + '');
});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="inputs">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Apple">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Orange">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Pineapple">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Mango">
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="target"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: btw since my textbox uses $("#keywords").keyup(function() to activate ajax to search without submit. So even tho when the checkbox's value is inputted into the textbox its not activating the ajax till I click the textbox and hit enter. Anyway to solve that? cheers

Comment: Just call your ajax search funcion in checkboxes change event handler.

Comment: @kamilkp: as a sidenote, keep in mind that just a link is not a good quality answer. It's best to also include the (relevant) code so even when the link ever dies the content remains. I have taken the liberty to do this for you already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

<kbd>[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/Z2X9P/)</kbd>

here you just need to apply a `click` event on all your check boxes.
and fill the input box on every click.